# Read special characters from .txt file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, unicode

The goal of this code is to find the frequency of words used in a book.

I am tying to read in the text of a book but the following line keeps throwing my code off:

> precious *protégés*. No, gentlemen; he'll always show 'em a clean pair
>
> specifically the é character

I have looked at the following documentation, but I don't quite understand it: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html

Heres my code:

```
import string
# Create word dictionary from the comprehensive word list 
word_dict = {}
def create_word_dict ():

  # open words.txt and populate dictionary
  word_file = open ("./words.txt", "r")
  for line in word_file:
    line = line.strip()
    word_dict[line] = 1

# Removes punctuation marks from a string
def parseString (st):
  st = st.encode("ascii", "replace")
  new_line = ""
  st = st.strip()
  for ch in st:
    ch = str(ch)
    if (n for n in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)) in ch or ' ' in ch or ch.isspace() or ch == u'\xe9':

      print (ch)
      new_line += ch
    else:
      new_line += ""
  # now remove all instances of 's or ' at end of line
  new_line = new_line.strip()
  print (new_line)
  if (new_line[-1] == "'"):
    new_line = new_line[:-1]
  new_line.replace("'s", "")
  # Conversion from ASCII codes back to useable text
  message = new_line
  decodedMessage = ""
  for item in message.split():
    decodedMessage += chr(int(item))
  print (decodedMessage)
  return new_line

# Returns a dictionary of words and their frequencies
def getWordFreq (file):

  # Open file for reading the book.txt
  book = open (file, "r")

  # create an empty set for all Capitalized words
  cap_words = set()

  # create a dictionary for words
  book_dict = {}
  total_words = 0

  # remove all punctuation marks other than '[not s]
  for line in book:
    line = line.strip()
    if (len(line) > 0):
      line = parseString (line)

    word_list = line.split()

    # add words to the book dictionary
    for word in word_list:
      total_words += 1
      if (word in book_dict):
        book_dict[word] = book_dict[word] + 1
      else:
        book_dict[word] = 1
  print (book_dict)

  # close the file
  book.close()

def main():
  wordFreq1 = getWordFreq ("./Tale.txt")
  print (wordFreq1)

main()
```

The error that I received is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Books.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "Books.py", line 77, in main
    wordFreq1 = getWordFreq ("./Tale.txt")
  File "Books.py", line 60, in getWordFreq
    line = parseString (line)
  File "Books.py", line 36, in parseString
    decodedMessage += chr(int(item))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: You might have checked already, otherwise do check the encoding of the incoming data. Is it in UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, WIN-1252 OR UCS-2? Nothing like expecting UTF-8 and coming across a character with the high bit set that is not UTF-8 but an 8 bit character.

Comment: I wasn't able to find out how how to check the encoding in notepad? but I also use iPython. How can I find out?

Comment: Under Windows NotePad++ can give you a clue. On Linux the "file" command will tell you. Or use a hex viewer or binary editor to see the actual bytes in the passage.

Comment: In notepad the encoding was set to ANSI

Comment: In removing punctuation marks, do you mean get rid of the `é` character altogether or turn it into plain `e`?

Comment: Please indent each line of your tracebacks by 4 spaces (like code) to make them more readable.

Comment: removing punctuation marks such as:  :!.; and the like.  The goal of this function is to return a line of text with only letters, spaces, and instances of '{insert character that is not s}.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you open a text file in python, the encoding is ANSI by default, so it doesn't contain your é chartecter. Try

```
word_file = open ("./words.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: What the encoding is by default, [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64505635).

Comment: "ANSI by default"? Where did you get that from? [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) say: "if `encoding` is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent".

Answer (score 1):

The best way I could think of is to read each character as an ASCII value, into an array, and then take the char value. For example, 97 is ASCII for "a" and if you do char(97) it will output "a". Check out some online ASCII tables that provide values for special characters also.

Comment: No ASCII table worth its storage space will contain accented characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def parseString(st):
    st = st.encode("ascii", "replace")

    # rest of code here
```

The new error you are getting is because you are calling isalpha on an int (i.e. a number)

Try this:

```
for ch in st:
    ch = str(ch)
    if (n for n in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) if n in ch) or ' ' in ch or ch.isspace() or ch == u'\xe9':

        print (ch)
```

Comment: I get the following error:    File "Books.py", line 30
    st = st.encode("ascii", "replace)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I updated the code, which produces a new error message

Comment: The new error is because `str.encode()` returns a bytes object, not a string.

Comment: so now how do I convert these ascii values back into words. Because I need to make a dictionary of unique words that are used in this book. The code is working now but I am getting a dictionary filled with unique sets of numbers.

Comment: So I am trying to convert these words in ASCII characters back to text, however I receive a new error message

Comment: I still need some help on this one? Any suggestions on what I would be doing to fix this problem...

Comment: If you send me the text file Ill do it for you, difficult working without it.

Comment: How do I send you a file on this site?

Comment: Unless it's very confidential I would post it's content here, if it's not long.

Comment: Otherwise svenvarennes gmail