# Opening file in py2app built program using macOS Sierra

Tags: python, file-handling, macos-sierra, py2app

(Noobwarning, just started trying to learn programming a few weeks back and are working with python 3.6 in intelliJ on macOS Sierra)

Im working on a program that should read a text file and insert labels with tkinter with the data from the file. 
Everything works fine in intelliJ, but when building the app with py2app it crashes instantly with error "Detected missing constraints for ."

I have stripped the code to find whats causing it, and it is the open file command. A python file just containing this little code crashes:

```
with open(sample.txt) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

The way it is implemented in my code is:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
file = path + "/sample.txt"
```

..............

```
list_one = []
list_two = []
try:
    with open(file) as listofstuff:
        for line in listofstuff:
            filed_one, field_two = tuple(line.strip('\n').split('\t'))

            list_one.append(field_one)
            list_two.append(field_two)
except Exception:
    labelNotfound = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, text='{} is missing'.format(file))
    labelNotfound.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

The Exception will prevent the crash, but it will never find the file. The (file) printed in the tkinter label at last line shows the exact path that the file is located, with the nameofapp.app/Contents/Resources/sample.txt

Whats going wrong?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. My python executes without an error. This leaves me to question: are you sure the file path is correct since `nameofapp.app/Contents/Resources/sample.txt` can never be correct but `/nameofapp.app/Contents/Resources/sample.txt` might be.. Also, it seems good practice to also add a [mode](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to the open statement, e.g. like `open(file, 'r')` to make sure you have the correct access.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full and exact error you are getting? Also, could you post the output of `ls -l` when applied to your `sample.txt` file.

Comment: First question, the path is correct, but I did not print the full in my question, when I "print(file)" it show complete path "/Users/pergustafson/IdeaProjects/projectname/dist/filename.app/Contents/Resources/sample.txt". I will get back later with a complete code example and complete error. Ive changed my code to instead pick up the list from a separate .py file that gets included in the .app and also in the .exe for windows. That works fine, but would like to use the .txt instead so user could change the values.

Comment: If you add your output of `ls -l` we can make sure it is not a permission error.

Comment: ls -l shows: -rw-r--r--@ 1 pergustafson  staff   56 Mar 31 18:25 sample.txt

Comment: Thanks SB87, believe you made me fix it myself:) Since I had my code full of variables and comments in Swedish I copied it to a new project and rewrote/shortened down other parts that didn't have anything to do with the error... And suddenly it runs fine.... Still can't see why the original file wouldn't work, but will have to trough it again.

Comment: Error wasn't really in the code, but in the txt file. Using the Swedish letters åäö or ÅÄÖ cause the crash. There must be a workaround I guess, but have been focusing at the wrong place...

Comment: Ah! great. You could try `open("sample.txt", encoding='utf-8')` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159202/4041795)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Thanks a lot. I had given this up and imported the list from a python file instead, but that ment building a new file instead of letting the user change.

Comment: If you still have the original error message you could post it as an answer with your findings. That way the question can be marked as solved :).