# Reading a file with french characters in Python

Tags: python, file, python-unicode

I would like to read a file that contains french characters in Python such "é".I'm using these lines of code to do that:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(r'C:\Users\chsafouane\Desktop\saf.txt', encoding='ascii') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line
```

Yet, I get a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To reproduce the error, the file I'm trying to read contains only one word: "Accélération". Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read special characters from .txt file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219774/read-special-characters-from-txt-file-in-python)

Comment: If the file has been created on Windows, `encoding='latin1'` may work better than `encoding='utf-8'` to retrieve the correct characters

Comment: @sciroccorics Yes latin1 encoding works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For a fie including only this word "Accélération", utf-8 encodinf doesn't work and it returns the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

As proposed by @sciroccorics, `latin-1`  encoding works well and it returns the right word. So the chunk of code that works is the following:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(r'C:\Users\chsafouane\Desktop\saf.txt', encoding='latin1') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Does not work for the french character `"œ"`.

Answer (score 0):

try 'cp1252', works fine for me for all French chars