# Kedro install fail to install, but few attempt later it is successful

Tags: python, pipeline, kedro

I have to test if my kedro project works from github so I create a new environment, then :

```
git clone <my_project>
pip install kedro kedro[pandas] kedro-viz jupyter
kedro build-reqs
kedro install
```

and the install fails, then I retry a few time (sometimes 2 or 3) then the next attempt it is successful

[image: see image]

EDIT:
python -V : Python 3.7.10
kedro --version : kedro, version 0.17.3

i cant post my requirement.txt (post is mostly code) so here is my requirement.in

```
black==v19.10b0
flake8>=3.7.9, <4.0
ipython==7.10
isort>=4.3.21, <5.0
jupyter~=1.0
jupyter_client>=5.1, <7.0
jupyterlab==0.31.1
kedro==0.17.3
nbstripout==0.3.3
pytest-cov~=2.5
pytest-mock>=1.7.1, <2.0
pytest~=6.1.2
wheel==0.32.2
spacy>=3.0.0,<4.0.0
scikit-learn == 0.24.2
kedro-viz==3.11.0
wordcloud== 1.8.1
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/fr_core_news_sm-3.0.0/fr_core_news_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz#egg=fr_core_news_sm
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue using Kedro's [spaceflights starter](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/02_get_started/06_starters.html). Could you please add your Python version, Kedro version, and ideally the link to the project (or at least its `requirements.txt`)?

Comment: Based on the error traceback it looks like there are two issues: (1) `kedro install` is erroring out, (2) the actual error is being obscured by a decoding error on [this line](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/master/kedro/framework/cli/project.py#L172). Does `pip install -r requirements.txt` work on your project?

Comment: It seems like 'pip install -r requirements.txt' is sucessful, can you explain why I dont understand.. I tought kedro install used pip install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, I think there are two issues at play.

##### 1. Decoding error

This is the main exception you're getting, i.e.:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode byte 0xe8 in position 69: invalid continuation byte
```

This is unexpectedly raised while Kedro itself is handling the errors from `pip install` (see [this line of Kedro's source code](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/blob/master/kedro/framework/cli/project.py#L172)). I believe the cause might be that you have accented characters in your working directory, which can't be interpreted by Python's standard `decode()` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898909/reading-a-file-with-french-characters-in-python)). Example:

```
b'accélération'.decode()
>> SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

The decoding error is obscuring the actual `pip install` error.

##### 2. `pip install` error

As you correctly pointed out, `kedro install` uses `pip install` under the hood. It's a bit difficult to pinpoint the exact cause without seeing the actual error. I could however reproduce a similar issue, in my case getting the following error:

```sh
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\<mu-user>\\anaconda3\\<my-env>\\kedro_project_tests\\lib\\site-packages\\~ydantic\\annotated_types.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I believe this is caused by interactions caused by between different versions Kedro and Kedro-Viz. Simply not `pip install`ing `kedro-viz` *before* doing `kedro install` fixed it for me.

---

*Note: Related to this, there will surely be an error if the version of Kedro installed through `pip` *before* doing `kedro install` is not the same as the version of Kedro specified in `requirements.in` or `requirements.txt`. This is obvious, as the package currently handling execution will be uninstalled. The error in this case will be something like this:*

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\<my-user>\\anaconda3\\envs\\<my-env>\\scripts\\kedro.exe
```