# Wrong encoding when reading file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

When I read a file in python and print it to the screen, it does not read certain characters properly, however, those same characters hard coded into a variable print just fine. Here is an example where "test.html" contains the text "Hallå":

```
with open('test.html','r') as file:
    Str = file.read()
print(Str)
Str = "Hallå"
print(Str)
```

This generates the following output:

```
hallÃ¥
Hallå
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with how the data in the file is being interpreted when it is read into Python, however I am uncertain of what it is since Python 3.8.5 already uses UTF-8 encoding by default.

Comment: Change the `encoding` argument of `open()` - e.g. `with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='...') as file:`. This requires you know the encoding of the file beforehand, though

Comment: You may have encoded the file incorrectly. Can you show us what happens when you write `"Hallå"` to the file using Python?

Comment: This may be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding. What does `locale.getdefaultencoding()` say and how does that compare to the expected encoding of the file?

Comment: Can you open the file in binary and post its contents `print(open('test.html', 'rb').read()`? Add that to what `getdefaultencoding` says and we can experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `open` does **not** use UTF-8 by default. As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says:

> In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

So, it depends, and to be certain, you have to specify the encoding yourself. If the file is saved in UTF-8, you should do this:

```
with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

On the other hand, it is not clear whether the file is or is not saved in UTF-8 encoding. If it is not, you'll have to choose a different one.